# Using NSSM to start a NodeJs process as a windows service is not working

Tags: node.js, windows-services

I have seen countless articles on how to use NSSM (http://nssm.cc/) to start a NodeJS process.

So, I have the following simple NodeJS file:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('<p>Hello World</p>');
}).listen(8000);

console.log('Server running on http://localhost:8000/');
```

I am using this command to install the NodeJS file as a windows service:

> "C:\Program Files\SimpleNode\nssm.exe" install SimpleNode "C:\Program Files\SimpleNode\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\SimpleNode\simple.js"

The service is installed.  When I start it I get an error message, the services is in the Paused state and I see the following error in Event Viewer:

> GetProcessTimes() failed: The handle is invalid.

This should be pretty simple.  I have tried using a domain account that has local admin rights.  I have tried a couple of different port numbers.  The app does work correctly when I start it from the command line.

MORE NOTES:
This is running on 64-bit Windows 2008 R2 server.  I have made sure I am running all 64-bit executables for both NSSM and Node.  I have also tried using 32-bit executables for both.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?  Can someone else replicate this issue?

Answer (score 16):

Found the issue.

The problem is that is that the path to the simple.js file has a space in it (Good Old "Program Files").  You have to escape the quotes with a backslash for NSSM to interpret it correctly.  The correct installation command line is:

> "C:\Program Files\SimpleNode\nssm.exe" install SimpleNode "C:\Program Files\SimpleNode\node.exe" \"C:\Program Files\SimpleNode\simple.js\"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have access to ports for some reason. try setting the service to run as administrator (server Manager>Services>Servicename on windows server 2008) and see what happens.

Comment: No, I have tried that.  I will edit my question with some of the things that I have tried.

Comment: weird, when I had a similar issue (windows server 2008) this worked

Answer (score -2):

NSSM usually works fine with Node.js so this is probably a permissions issue. Review this [tutorial showing how to setup Node.js with our commercial application](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunNodeJSAsAService.html) to troubleshoot. And feel free to use the 30-day trial too as it it may return a more helpful error message indicating what the problem is.

Comment: AlwaysOn made me use the 32-bit version of Node.exe.  And that works with AlwaysOn.  I made sure that I had the 32-bit version of both NSSM and Node and it still gives me the same issue.