# running a server file on node.js

Tags: node.js

I've been practicing with "hello world" examples of websockets and node.js server.
According to all those examples you create a `html` file (client) and a `js` file (server).
Before you run them, you have to run this on the command line (I use windows)

```
 node nameOFtheServer.js
```

So, my question. *If I close the command line window and open it again the client does not connect to the server.* I have to run again the above code in the command line , manually, so the server will start again. Why is this happening? Is that normal? How can I fix it , so I dont have to run the same commands over and over again on the command line in order to start the `js` file (server) ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

OK, new facts, I just edited the question, highlighting the changes in Italics

Comment: You should post some code

Comment: Not normal, and we need to see your code to know why it isn't working

Comment: Oh well, I'm off ....... for future reference, showing us how you run the .js file is rather less useful than posting the contents of the javascript and the html (or as small a test example as you can make)

Comment: @iandotkelly I have two files. `helloserver.js` has the code from this [link](http://cjihrig.com/blog/websockets-in-node-js-0-8-6-for-windows-7/) and `helloclient.html` has the code from this [link](http://cjihrig.com/blog/creating-your-own-websocket-echo-client/) .The only difference is that I change the port to listen to 1337. Hmm...maybe is somethong about the port? I have to "activate" it?

Comment: @iandotkelly Apparently, I did not understand what you asked me. I run the `js` file by simply typing `node helloserver.js`. Sorry, i did not get you...

Comment: what is the output in the command window when you run the server?

Comment: @SteveHaigh You mean after I run the `node helloserver.js` ? Its `Sun Jul 14 2013 00:59:12 GMT+0300 (Θερινή ώρα GTB) Server is listening on port 1337`. "Θερινή ώρα" that's Greek for "Summer time" (I'm Greek and I have my system in greek). So after that, server runs fine and the command window also displays the connections and the messages etc. But as I mentioned, if I close the html file and open it again , I have to manually restart the server

Comment: @slevin - what I mean is that node.js developers know how to start node.js applications e.g. 'node helloserver.js', so this information is not going to help us answer your question.  What will help us answer your question would be for you to edit your question to include some of your code - the key parts of the helloserver.js and the html file.  If the files are small - post all of them.

Comment: OK, when you start the client and clikc "connect" do you see "Connection accepted" on the server, and when you kill the client do you see "Peer 127.0.0.1 disconnected". Does the client page work when it is connected? The samples you point to all work fine for me.

Comment: @SteveHaigh Yes , the client page works fine when is connected. But if I close the command window and open the client page again, does not connect unless I start server file manually using command line

Comment: @iandotkelly The files are big, that's why I gave links. The code I have is the same as the links, just a simple copy/paste. The only difference is I changed the port to 1337.

Comment: @slevin - thanks, I didn't see the link in the comment, sorry.  Anyway, I see the question has changed quite a bit and you have a good answer now.

Comment: @slevin ... "if I close the command window" ... Ah. Well, there's your answer. Keep the window open or use the solutions below from Venemo :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you close the terminal, everything that runs in it is killed. There are many solutions on both Linux and Windows systems, most of them create some sort of a service which then runs in the background.

Here are some possible solutions:

- http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever
- https://github.com/indexzero/daemon.node
- http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunNodeJSAsAService.html
- http://coreybutler.github.io/node-windows/manual/#!/api/nodewindows.Service

Pick the one that is best for you.

Related question on StackOverflow:

- [How to run node.js app forever when console is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818202/how-to-run-node-js-app-forever-when-console-is-closed)

Comment: Thanks. Can you name a solution(s) for Windows?

Comment: @slevin I edited my answer to include some possible solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks Venemo for your anser. I tried use the forever module, but did not worked well, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660551/forever-module-on-node-js-doesnt-work-warnings).

So I decided to use [nssm](http://nssm.cc/) with node.js

I [download](http://nssm.cc/download/?page=download) the nssm and unzip it in the `C:Program Files\path\to\nodejs`. And then I opened Window's command window and typed `C:\program files\path\to\nssm-2.16\win32` and then typed `nssm.exe`. You should see a "menu" how to install or remove services. And now type

```
"C:\Program Files\path\to\nssm.exe" install give-Your-Service-A-Name "C:\path\to\node.exe" \"C:Program Files\nodejs\path\to\yourServerFile.js"
```

Notice the `\` before the `"C:Program Files\nodejs\path\to\yourServerFile.js"` it's not a typo, you should type it, is important, if you have spaces in your path, helps nssm to interpret correctly.

And that's it, now press CTRL+ALT+DEL, open the Services tab, and find give-Your-Service-A-Name , right click and select `Start service`. To check, open your client file that communicates with the yourServerFile.js, it should be working, without having to start the yourServerFile.js from command line.

(PS : I use nodejs 0.10.12 and nssm 2.16 on windows 7. The instructions above are a combination of this [tutorial](http://harjinderkamboj.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/running-node-as-a-service-using-nssm-2/) and this [anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427301/using-nssm-to-start-a-nodejs-process-as-a-windows-service-is-not-working))