# forever module on node.js doesn't work - warnings

Tags: node.js

I use windows 7 and nodejs 0.10.12. I installed the latest version of forever module like so

```
npm install -g forever
```

and then I typed

```
forever start helloserver.js
```

And I get the following

```
warn: --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn: --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info: Forever processing file: helloserver.js
```

Now , I type

```
forever list
```

just to check and I get

```
info: No forever processes running
```

Also note that during the installation of forever I got these warnings

```
package.json eyes@0.1.8 No repository field.
package.json eventemitter2@0.4.11 No repository field.
package.json eventemitter2@0.4.11 'repositories' (plural) Not supported
package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' filed
package.json aws-sign@0.2.0 No readme data
package.json cookie-jar@0.2.0 No readme data
package.json oauth-sign@0.2.0 No readme data
package.json tunnel-agent@0.2.0 No readme data
package.json forever-agent@0.2.0 No readme data
engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v.0.10.12","npm":"1.2.32"})
engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v.0.10.12","npm":"1.2.32"})
engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v.0.10.12","npm":"1.2.32"})
engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v.0.10.12","npm":"1.2.32"})
engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v.0.10.12","npm":"1.2.32"})
```

I guess the forever module is not installed correctly so cannot run the server? I don't get it and I cant think of a solution. Any suggestions/tips? Should I use node 0.8.x? Or there is a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: `forever` is used to make it easy to run Services on various platforms. This is helpful because the various Linux distros vary wildly on how they implement Services. However, on a Windows 7 box, configuring Services is easy and well-documented. I would skip `forever` and simply use the existing Windows Services stuff.

Comment: @GatesVP If I get it, you suggest I should stop worrying about the `Forever` and install the `helloserver.js` as a service on Windows. Right?

Comment: Well the Service will probably be a call to `node c:\path\to\helloserver.js`, but that's the premise. Windows Services will provide you with the basic `forever` features like starting when the computer starts, automatic restart on failure, etc. If you need the command-line access, PowerShell will grant you full access to the services stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I think Forever, last version (0.10.0), work on Windows instability but not Linux. You can try following but i recommend you should choose another resolve.

```
forever start -c node script.js
```

Note: you can't list and stop in forever with "forever list".